# Regular expressions failed match

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match this text:
 `[ButtonWrap title="Button" size="Big"][Button]test Button[/Button][/ButtonWrap]` by this regex `\[ButtonWrap([^\]]*][^\[]*)\[\/ButtonWrap]`, I tested it in this site  http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html but the Result `No match was found!`
what the error in the regex ?

Comment: I don't get the point of `[^\[][^\][]*`...

Comment: You did not escaped the last "]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the logic of your attempt but you might want this :

```
\[ButtonWrap(.*?)\[\/ButtonWrap]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
\[ButtonWrap.+?\]\[.+?\].*?\[/.+?\]\[/ButtonWrap\]
```

[**Demo**](http://regexr.com?373fp)

It matches the `ButtonWrap`-tag including attributes, then any other kind of tag, some text and the corresponding closing tags.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181774/stricter-kbd-usage-rules

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what most of the inner stuff is for but I think this should be sufficient:

`\[ButtonWrap(.)*\](.)*\[\/ButtonWrap\]`